# Lookup field is not working properly

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a problem to create lookup field for custom object. Lookup icon is not appeared in my visualforce page.
This is my coding.
Controller:

```
public class StudentLookup{
 public List<Student_Sports_Registration__c> getStudents(){
   return [SELECT Email__c,Name FROM Student_Sports_Registration__c];
 }
 public Student_Sports_Registration__c getStudent_Sports(){
   Id id = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id'); 
  return id == null ? new Student_Sports_Registration__c() : [SELECT Email__c, Name FROM Student_Sports_Registration__c WHERE Id = :id]; }
  }
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="StudentLookup">
<apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock title="My Content">
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
   <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Lookup to an Account" for="theLookup"/>
       <apex:inputField id="theLookup" value="{!Student_Sports.Id}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Lookup will appear if the field is defined as the lookup in the database

Simple example will be if you need Account lookup on contact then you will use

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!contact.AccountId}"/>
```

So you cannot simply provide an Id and expect lookup out of it .If you have a child object that refers to the Student_Sports_Registration__c as the parent ,you can use that as lookup else you will have to roll your own solution here using below sample approach

[Roll your own custom window](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/)